# Generate random points above and below a line in Python

Tags: python, random

I would like to generate random points on an x,y scatter plot that are either above or below a given line. For example, if the line is y=x I would like to generate a list of points in the top left of the plot (above the line) and a list of points in the bottom right of the plot (below the line). Here's is an example where the points are above or below y=5:

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

num_points = 10
x1 = [random.randrange(start=1, stop=9) for i in range(num_points)]
x2 = [random.randrange(start=1, stop=9) for i in range(num_points)]
y1 = [random.randrange(start=1, stop=5) for i in range(num_points)]
y2 = [random.randrange(start=6, stop=9) for i in range(num_points)]

plt.scatter(x1, y1, c='blue')
plt.scatter(x2, y2, c='red')
plt.show()
```

[image: Random point plot]

However, I generated the x and y points independently, which limits me to equations where y = c (where c is a constant). How can I expand this to any y=mx+b?

Comment: Setting aside the question of the actual distribution you're hoping for, since you're generating the x and y coordinates separately, couldn't you just generate the x coordinates and then compute the range for each corresponding y coordinate using your constraint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the stop and start limits for `y1` and `y2` to be the line you want. You will need to decide where the plane ends (set `lower` and `upper`).

Note this only works for integers. You can use truncated multivariate distributions if you want something more sophisticated.

```
m, b = 1, 0
lower, upper = -25, 25

x1 = [random.randrange(start=1, stop=9) for i in range(num_points)]
x2 = [random.randrange(start=1, stop=9) for i in range(num_points)]

y1 = [random.randrange(start=lower, stop=m*x+b) for x in x1]
y2 = [random.randrange(start=m*x+b, stop=upper) for x in x2]

plt.plot(np.arange(10), m*np.arange(10)+b)
plt.scatter(x1, y1, c='blue')
plt.scatter(x2, y2, c='red')
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You may as well have my answer too.

This way puts Gaussian noise above the line, and below. I have deliberately set the mean of the noise to 20 so that it would stand out from the line, which is y = 10*x + 5. You would probably make the mean zero.

```
>>> import random
>>> def y(x, m, b):
...     return m*x + b
... 
>>> import numpy as np
>>> X = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
>>> y_above = [y(x, 10, 5) + abs(random.gauss(20,5)) for x in X]
>>> y_below = [y(x, 10, 5) - abs(random.gauss(20,5)) for x in X]
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> plt.scatter(X, y_below, c='g')
>>> plt.scatter(X, y_above, c='r')
>>> plt.show()
```

Here's the plot.

[image: scatter plot]

Answer (score 1):

There are many approaches possible, but if your only requirement is that they are above and below the y = mx + b line, then you can simply plug the random x values into the equation and then add or subtract a random y value.

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

slope = 1
intercept = 0

def ymxb(slope, intercept, x):
    return slope * x + intercept

num_points = 10
x1 = [random.randrange(start=1, stop=9) for i in range(num_points)]
x2 = [random.randrange(start=1, stop=9) for i in range(num_points)]
y1 = [ymxb(slope, intercept, x) - random.randrange(start=1, stop=9) for x in x1]
y2 = [ymxb(slope, intercept, x) + random.randrange(start=1, stop=9) for x in x2]

plt.scatter(x1, y1, c='blue')
plt.scatter(x2, y2, c='red')
plt.show()
```

That looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Side of (x, y) is defined by the sign of `y - mx - b`. You can read it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/757591/how-to-determine-the-side-on-which-a-point-lies), for example.

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

num_points = 50
x = [random.randrange(start=1, stop=9) for i in range(num_points)]
y = [random.randrange(start=1, stop=9) for i in range(num_points)]
m = 5
b = -3

colors = ['blue' if y[i] - m * x[i] - b > 0 else 'red' for i in range(num_points) ]
plt.plot([0, 10], [b, 10 * m + b], c='green')
plt.xlim((0, 10))
plt.ylim((0, 10))

plt.scatter(x, y, c=colors)
plt.show()
```

[image]