# Generating a random float below and above a line created by numpy arrays python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to generate a random float point above and below a line created by numpy arrays.

For example I have these line equations:

```
x_values = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)

y1 = 2 * x_values -5
y2= -3 * x_values +2

plt.plot(x_values,y1, '-k')
plt.plot(x_values,y2, '-g')
```

I have tried this method from [Generate random points above and below a line in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46417259/generate-random-points-above-and-below-a-line-in-python) and it works if `np.arrange` is used like so:

```
lower, upper = -25, 25

num_points = 1
x1 = [random.randrange(start=1, stop=9) for i in range(num_points)]
x2 = [random.randrange(start=1, stop=9) for i in range(num_points)]

y1 = [random.randrange(start=lower, stop=(2 * x -5) )for x in x1]
y2 = [random.randrange(start=(2 * x -5), stop=upper) for x in x2]

plt.plot(np.arange(10), 2 * np.arange(10) -5)
plt.scatter(x1, y1, c='blue')
plt.scatter(x2, y2, c='red')
```

However, I wanted to find a way to generate a random point if `np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)` was used to create the line graph. The difference is involving/allowing float coordinates to be picked to. But unsure how.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Randomly select an `x` coordinate from your *linspace*, then generate a random float and add or subtract it from that x coordinate's y value. `unsure how` which part are you unsure about? You should try something - read through the docs, pick something, try it, evaluate, adjust, repeat.  This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: I was quite clear in what I was asking. Randomly selecting a single point above and below a line created by np.linspace rather than np. arange, which involves floats rather than just intergers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach, using functions for the y-values. Random x positions are chosen uniformly over the x-range. For each random x, a value is randomly chosen between its y-ranges.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_values = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
f1 = lambda x: 2 * x - 5
f2 = lambda x: -3 * x + 2

y1 = f1(x_values)
y2 = f2(x_values)

plt.plot(x_values, y1, '-k')
plt.plot(x_values, y2, '-g')
plt.fill_between (x_values, y1, y2, color='gold', alpha=0.2)

num_points = 20
xs = np.random.uniform(x_values[0], x_values[-1], num_points)
ys = np.random.uniform(f1(xs), f2(xs))
plt.scatter(xs, ys, color='crimson')

plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

PS: Note that the simplicity of the approach chooses x uniform over its length.  If you need an even distribution over the area of the trapezium, you need the x less probable at the right, and more at the left. You can visualize this with many more points and using transparency. With the simplistic approach, the right will look denser than the left.

The following code first generates x,y points in a parallelogram, and remaps the points on the wrong side back to its mirror position. The code looks like:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x0, x1 = -1, 1
x_values = np.linspace(x0, x1, 100)
f1 = lambda x: 2 * x - 5
f2 = lambda x: -3 * x + 2

y1 = f1(x_values)
y2 = f2(x_values)
plt.plot(x_values, y1, '-k')
plt.plot(x_values, y2, '-g')
plt.fill_between(x_values, y1, y2, color='gold', alpha=0.2)

num_points = 100_000
h0 = f2(x0) - f1(x0)
h1 = f2(x1) - f1(x1)
xs1 = np.random.uniform(x0, x1, num_points)
ys1 = np.random.uniform(0, h0 + h1, num_points) + f1(xs1)
xs = np.where(ys1 <= f2(xs1), xs1, x0 + x1 - xs1)
ys = np.where(ys1 <= f2(xs1), ys1, f1(xs) + h0 + h1 + f1(xs1) - ys1)
plt.scatter(xs, ys, color='crimson', alpha=0.2, ec='none', s=1)
plt.show()
```

Plot comparing the two approaches:

[image: comparison plot]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you have 2 intersecting lines, there will most likely be a triangle in which you can pick random points. This is dangerously close to Bertrand's paradox, so make sure that your RNG suits its purpose.
If you don't really care about how "skewed" your randomness is, try this:

```
import numpy as np
left, right = -1, 1
# x_values = np.linspace(left, right, 100)
k1, k2 = 2, -3
b1, b2 = -5, 2
y1 = lambda x: k1*x + b1
y2 = lambda x: k2*x + b2

# If you need a point above the 1st equation, but below the second one.
# Check the limits where you can pick the points under this condition.
nosol = False
if k1==k2:
    if b1>=b2:
        inters = -100
        nosol = True
    else:
        rand_x = np.random.uniform(left,right)
        rand_y = np.random.uniform(y1(rand_x),y2(rand_x))
        print(f'Random point is ({round(rand_x,2)}, {round(rand_y,2)})')
else:
    inters = (b2-b1)/(k1-k2)
if inters<=left:
    if k1>=k2:
        nosol=True
elif inters>=right:
    if k1<=k2:
        nosol=True
if nosol:
    print('No solution')
else:
    if k1>k2:
        right = inters
    else:
        left = inters
    # Pick random X between "left" and "right"
    # Pick whatever distribution you like or need
    rand_x = np.random.uniform(left,right)
    rand_y = np.random.uniform(y1(rand_x),y2(rand_x))
    print(f'Random point is ({round(rand_x,2)}, {round(rand_y,2)})')
```

If your random X needs to belong to a specific number sequence, use some other `np.random` function: `randint`, `choice`...

Comment: Nothing wrong with this, I just prefer the simplicity of @JohanC

Comment: @Nic If that is a general task for any `k` and `b` and the order of the lines matters, make sure you check if there is a solution first.